# Is there any way to fix the error "Customer cus_xxx already has the maximum 25 current and scheduled subscriptions" in Stripe?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I am having problem with creating stripe subscription. i think they allow only 25 current and scheduled subscriptions. Also i checked the [stripe customer settings page](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/customers/cus_xxx) and [overall Stripe Settings page](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings) to update the limit. But there is no option available. I got the following error in stripe.

```
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Customer cus_xxx already has the maximum 25 current and scheduled subscriptions.; code: customer_max_subscriptions; request-id: req_cysxx
at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.handleApiError(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:792)
at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.staticRequest(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:553)
at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:78)
at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:228)
at com.stripe.model.Subscription.create(Subscription.java:439)
at com.stripe.model.Subscription.create(Subscription.java:432)
at controllers.Stripe.Newcheckout(Stripe.java:264)
```

In my application a customer is admin. so he need to make more than 25 subscriptions.
Please advice

Answer (score 1):

From Stripe reply:

Creating more than 25 subscriptions on one customer is definitely uncommon. This would mean that for a monthly plan for example your customer would be charged 25+ times a month on the same card which usually leads to a higher rate of declines. You can read more about managing multiple subscriptions here: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/multiplan

What we usually advise in those situations is to use the quantity parameter on the subscription [0] so that you end up grouping multiple $10 a month subscriptions for example into one invoice. Do you think that solution would work for you? If not would you be able to describe your current business model and why you need multiple subscriptions in parallel for one customer? [0] https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quantities